# Vuejs + Vuex problem to handle state inside computed property

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm developing a very simple web app using Vuejs, Vuex and Axios. I'm blocked when I try to handle the value returned from a getters inside a computed property, I recive this error in console: *TypeError: "items is undefined"*, while in the Vue panel of DevTool the computed property has the correct value.

This is my Store:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    items: [],
},
actions: {
    LOAD_ITEMS_LIST: function ({ commit }) {
        axios.get('https://example.com/v1/items').then((response) => {
            commit('SET_ITEMS_LIST', { list: response.data })
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    },
},
mutations: {
    SET_ITEMS_LIST: (state, { list }) => {
        state.items = list
        },
},
getters: {
   items: state => {
        return  state.items;
    }, 
}
})
```

This my root component

```
var vm = new Vue({

el: '#app',
template: `<div>
                <items-list></items-list>
            </div>`,
store,
created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('LOAD_ITEMS_LIST')
},
});
```

This my ItemsList Component

```
Vue.component('items-list', {

template: ` <ul>
                <li v-for="item of items"> 
                   <h4>{{item.title}}</h4> 
                   <div class="excerpt">{{item.text}}</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            `,
computed: {
    items() {
        let items = this.$store.getters.items;
        return items.slice(0,10)
       },
     }
   })
```

**I noticed that if I return the items computed without modify the value this work well**, example:

```
items() {
        return this.$store.getters.items;
    }
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: At a hunch it's a reactivity issue: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: do you import `axios` in your vuex store?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim yes and it works well

Comment: could you share your code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)?, because i had tried an example like yours and it works fine

Comment: @webnoob I will read the link you sent me, for the moment I workaround the issue using a watch property on items and run a method which do the slide(0,10). But I think this isn't the best pratices and can be tedious for other computed property

Comment: I think your issue is that `slice` returns a new array - one that vue is not looking at but when you `watch` it, it forces vue to keep an eye on changes to it and in turn has the effect you need. There are ways you can change this using `this.$set`. That article should give the info.